# Convert multiple European date formats to single US format in R

Tags: r, date

How do I convert this column of dates with two formats into a date object with a single format? Dates are in dmy_hm and dmy_hms but I want them all in mdy_hm. I've tried as.date etc but receive NA values. Thank you!

Tried:
`format_ymd  <- as.Date(dat$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d") format_dmy  <- as.Date(dat$timestamp, format = "%d/%m/%Y") as.Date(ifelse(is.na(format_ymd), format_dmy, format_ymd), origin = "1970-01-01")`

and:
`parse_date_time(date_time, orders = c("dmY_HM", "dmY_HMS"))`

which did parse half of the values but the others were NA

and:
`addFormats(c('%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y')) dat$timestamp <- lapply(dat$timestamp,  function(x) format(anydate(x), "%d-%m-%Y"))`

Dates are in this format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw0xo.png)

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you can provide examples of how the data is formatted before you run your code on it. Please take a look at your data, find which rows demonstrate the different source formatting. Let's say row 1 has one format and row 50 has another and row 55 has a third. Run `dput(dat$timestamp[c(1, 50, 55)])` (but with your rows) and paste the output into the body of your question. Then we can try things out on data that is like yours.

Comment: In your example I see what might be `%d/%m/%y %H:%M` and `%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S` which vary (e.g. note %Y vs %y) from what you've tried. You might want `parse_date_time(date_time, orders = c("dmy_HM", "dmY_HMS"))`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(dates = c('12/5/22 21:00','13-05-2022 00:00:00'))

df

df %>% 
  mutate(dates1=format(as.POSIXct(dates,format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'), '%m%d%y_%H%M'),
         dates2=format(as.Date(dates, format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'),'%m%d%y_%H%M'),
         dates3=ifelse(is.na(dates1)==T, dates2,dates1),
         dates3=as.POSIXct(dates3, format='%m%d%y_%H%M'))
```

Note you have to handle the multiple formats first, then you can change the format however you like. After you may remove those columns used to create `dates3` which is the result I think you are looking for.

```
df2 <-   df %>% 
    mutate(dates1=format(as.POSIXct(dates,format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'), '%m%d%y_%H%M'),
           dates2=format(as.Date(dates, format = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'),'%m%d%y_%H%M'),
           dates3=ifelse(is.na(dates1)==T, dates2,dates1),
           dates3=as.POSIXct(dates3, format='%m%d%y_%H%M')) %>% 
  dplyr::select(dates3) %>% 
  rename(dates=dates3)
df2
```